Content Security Policy Issue: Tried to call API from server.ts file to update SEO meta tags in index.html but got CSP issue
I have installed axios and called API from server.ts.  I am getting below 2 issues:

Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-AF490//jIflwN/2nTDszvAx/KI2V9GJG8gdwvGhO/zw='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\GitHub_2024\CP24R1\SourceCode\Portals.Web\ClientApp\index'

By calling API from server.ts file I want to update the SEO tags. I tried different ways but unable to view the SEO meta tags updates in view page source. Hence, I am trying to update the SEO tags from srver.ts file. But I am getting issues.
Please some one provide solution or provide achievable approach for SEO implementation in Angular 17.
Need to implement SEO in angular 17 application. But meta tags are in index.html are not updating when page changed.
